# Calling a func() which is in parent component from a DynamicComponent

Tags: angular

What would be best way to call the function written in "main-component.ts" with in the DynamicComponent? (without creating it in DynamicComponent).

Within DynamicComponent:

```
 1. Constructing a template
 2. from <button (click)="myMethod(a,b)">Submit</button>
 3. It will try to identify the function from same "DynamicComponent"
 4. But this function is written in main-component.ts, how can we call this one?
```

[Tried this way...](https://plnkr.co/edit/OcKw6EO8zo5Yd5XAQfNb?p=preview)

**From app-component:** I am using `dynamic.getDOMElementOfDynamicTemplate('<input type="button" value="Click" (click)="clicked()">', this.vcRef)`

just below that we have the "clicked()" function, its not getting triggered.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Please add some code snippets or examples of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @Nelson, have added the plunkr in edits..

Comment: What's the problem with the code in the Plunker?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, the clicked() function is not getting called on compile of the template passed in to Dynamic Service.

Comment: That's expected. I linked to shared services above for a reason. Adding HTML with Angular bindings like `   dynamic.getDOMElementOfDynamicTemplate('<input type="button" value="Click" (click)="clicked()">', this.vcRef);
  ` is entirely pointless because `(click)` or similar Angular2 stuff **only** works in component templates and nowhere else.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, in comparison with Angularjs, $scope.parent, can't we get some sort of likely match in a child component ?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to hook the event to the parent. See plunkr below. Make sure you unsubscribe the event as well as it's not a HTTP observable.

https://plnkr.co/edit/qy2myWB4ZPbR6nwVhUjh?p=preview

```
this.subscription = compRef.instance.onClicked.subscribe(() => {
  this.clicked();
});
```

The other option is to use an external Event service as Günter posted above

Comment: event emitter would be always void ?

Comment: not always. It's up to you what you'd like to send in the payload

Comment: this is not practicable, since it triggers event for the clicks on the whole template anywhere..